# Startup files on raspberry pi 3

Tags: python, boot

I have 4 python scripts running continuously. How I can open them in separate windows on startup? I need see the terminals when it's booting up.

I tried `rc.local`: it's working but I can't see the terminals of each script.
I need that after reboot I can see 4 terminal windows like when I start scripts myself. There is way to do that?

Comment: Please see if my edit makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your using Raspbian Stretch with Desktop or Raspbian Buster with Desktop.

Edit the autostart file using:

```
sudo leafpad /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

Autostart file should look similar to:

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
@xscreensaver -no-splash
point-rpi
```

Add your 4 Python programs to the end using @lxterminal:

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
@xscreensaver -no-splash
point-rpi
@lxterminal -e python3 /home/pi/test1.py
@lxterminal -e python3 /home/pi/test2.py
@lxterminal -e python3 /home/pi/test3.py
@lxterminal -e python3 /home/pi/test4.py
```

Comment: it is launch scripts in /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart autostart folder?

Comment: No, my example launches scripts located in /home/pi (the path before the test<n>.py).

Comment: if script crashes ? where can find logs?